# 'Post' request not updating the data and giving error in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I am a newbie to NodeJS. I am trying to make a simple API relating to a bookstore.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser =  require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

Genre = require('./models/genre.js');
Book = require('./models/book.js');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/bookstore');
const db = mongoose.connection;

app.post('/api/genres', function(req, res) {
  const genre = req.body;
    Genre.addGenre(genre, function(err, genre) {
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(genre);
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Running on port 3000...');
```

Here is the genres.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

const genreSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String ,
        required: true
    },
    create_date:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

const Genre = module.exports = mongoose.model('Genre', genreSchema);
//Add Genre
module.exports.addGenre = function(genre, callback){
    Genre.create(genre, callback);
}
```

I tried both RestEasy and Postman. Get request is successful but nothing on Post request. It gives this error in the IDE when I make a request.

> ValidationError: Genre validation failed: name: Path `name` is
>   required.

Also, when I check on MongoShell it does not create date for books and genres.

Comment: You have left something out. A get request would never get caught by your `app.post` and you don't have a `const Genre = mongoose.model('Genre', genreSchema);` which **should** give a not-defined error at `Genre.create(...`

Comment: @ippi I didn't understand. Please explain a little, I am totally new to NodeJS.
and I didn't write the get method code here on purpose. It was working just fine.

Comment: In mongoose you create models from schemas and then use those models. But in the code above there is no model-call.  So inside your `genres.js` there is no `Genre`. This could should error out. And there is absolutely nothing here that handles a get-request. So maybe you have a lingering instance (old version of your app still running?) or you haven't restarted after changes. Because your problem description does not add up with the code.

Comment: If I had to guess wildly, I'd say CORS-errors because CORS doesn't happen with simple get-requests. try: `app.use(function(req,res,next){ res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); next(); });` before your other routes. But then again, postman doesn't care much about CORS.

Comment: I apologize, I forgot to paste that line here. I updated the code, check again.

Comment: I tried it out and it works for me, so probably just CORS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I tried it out and your code does work for me, so it probably was just CORS-problems after all.

This is how I made my test request:

```
<html>
<head><script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script></head>
<body>
    <script>
        axios
            .post('http://localhost:3000/api/genres', { name: "my genre" })
            .then(response => {
                document.body.innerHTML = 
                    `<pre>${JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 4)}</pre>`;
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This calls the request from localhost:80 and CORS-headers *are* needed if you request from another port. Still, I got big errors in my console:

```
Failed to load http://localhost:3000/api/genres: Request header field 
Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Meaning I missed a CORS-header I thought we didn't need. Sorry about that, updated headers:

```
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept, Accept-Language, Content-Language, Content-Type");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); 
    next();
});
```

---

And here is the complete code just to be thorough, including serving my index.html:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const path = require("path");

app.use(bodyParser.json());

Genre = require("./genre.js");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/bookstore");
const db = mongoose.connection;

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "index.html"));
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept, Accept-Language, Content-Language, Content-Type");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  next();
});

app.post("/api/genres", function(req, res) {
  const genre = req.body;
  Genre.addGenre(genre, function(err, genre) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    res.json(genre);
  });
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Running on port 3000...");
```

Comment: You get the validation error if you forget to pass in a name, (because your shema has name required) but I thought that was kinda obvious, sorry.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Also it updated the db in Mongo shell. Date is also created in shell.
but still don't know what wrong with Postman and RestEasy.

Comment: In postman try using Body: raw and change to JSON instead of form-data or form-urlencoded. (because you are using app.use(bodyParser.json());

Comment: How can I modify the post request to make work with the addbooks also. I tried to work with it but it is not working. Book have many properties i.e. title, author, publisher, pages etc.
I guess this part needs to be changed
`then(response => {
             document.body.innerHTML =
                 `<pre>${JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 4)}</pre>`;`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use the genre inside your req to create

```
module.exports.addGenre = function(genre, callback){
    Genre.create(genre, function (err, gen) {
         return callback(err, gen)
    })

}
```